# Decorators decorating base Commands

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am using SimpleInjector 2.2.3.0.

I have a MVC 4.0 project and am using the decorator pattern around my Commands to manage my UnitOfWork and my Authorisation. 
I have decorator which does authorisation - the `IAuthorisationDecorator`.  This wraps all of my `ITransactionalCommandHandlers`.
(Each `ITransactionalCommandHandler` is also decorated by `IUnitOfWorkDecorator`.) The authorisation decorator looks like this:

```
public void Handle(TCommand command)
{
    //authorise this command for this Iprincipal

    decoratedCommandHandler.Handle(command);
}
```

I now want to create a `INonTransactionalCommandHandler` (that doesn’t need an NHibernate session, it just does some File IO).
Note both `INonTransactionalCommandHandler` and `ITransactionalCommandHandler` inherit from `ICommandHandler` – which looks like so:

```
 public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand, out TResult>
 {
     TResult Result { get; }
     void Handle(TCommand command);
 }
```

I don’t really want to have to create two identical `AuthorisationDecorators` (transactional/non transactional).  Because ultimately they decorate a base `ICommandHandler` ( which is implemented as either a `ITransactional` or `INonTransactional`).

So my question is - Is there any way to create 1 Decorator that decorates a base `ICommandHandler` - but the container knows to cast up the `ICommandHandler` to a `ITransactionalCommandHandler` or an `INonTransactionalCommandHandler`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you register all command handlers by their `ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>` interface, you can't wrap part of the handlers with a decorator that wraps an `ITransactionalCommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>`. You can only apply such decorator if the handlers are explicitly registered by that `ITransactionalCommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>` interface, but this is not something you should do. You don't want that, since that means that the consumers of those commands need to know whether the handlers is transactional or not, which they shouldn't care about (it's a implementation detail).

Your transactional decorator should therefore wrap an `ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>`. If it needs access to the `ITransactionalCommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>` interface, the decorator should cast the input parameter from `ICommandHandler` to `ITransactionalCommandHandler`.

What you need is to register your decorators based on a predicate, as follows:

```
// NOTE: In Simple Injector v2.x use 'ManyForOpenGeneric' instead.
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>), myAssemblies);

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>), typeof(TransactionDecorator<,>), 
    c => typeof(ITransactionalCommandHandler<,>)
            .MakeGenericType(c.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments())
                .IsAssignableFrom(c.ImplementationType));

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>), typeof(AuthorisationDecorator<,>));
```

The predicate ensures that only command handlers are decorated that implement the `ITransactionalCommandHandler<,>`.

Instead of using that interface, you might also mark the handlers with an attribute:

```
[Transactional]
class ShipOrderCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<ShipOrderCommand, Unit> { ... }
```

In that case the registration would become:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>), typeof(TransactionDecorator<,>), 
    c => c.ImplementationType.GetCustomAttribute<TransactionalAttribute>() != null);
```

Yet another option is to mark the command itself with an interface or inherit from a base class:

```
public class ShipOrderCommand : ICommand<Unit>, ITransactionalCommand
{
    public Guid OrderId;
}
```

This allows you to add a generic type constraint on the `TransactionDecorator<,>` and allows you to remove the predicate on the `RegisterDecorator` registration:

```
public class TransactionDecorator<int TCommand, out TResult>
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>
    where TCommand : ITransactionalCommand
{
    // etc
}
```

Since Simple Injector understands type constraints, you can simplify the registration as follows:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<,>), typeof(TransactionDecorator<,>));
```

Do note that I don't advice this last approach in this particular case, since implementing an `ITransactionalCommand` interface on the command again means that implementation details are leaking into the definition of the command. The command and its consumers don't need to know about whether transactions are needed on the command handler (and this is something that might change in the future).

Comment: pipped to the post again!

Comment: Thanks that is working nicely.  I opted for the 1st option so some of my commandhandlers implement ITransactionalCommandHandler - however the authorisation can now be generic as the decorators only deal with ICommandHandlers. I get your point about the Leak of the Transaction implementation into the CommandHandler, but I think the other options suffer the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can decorate your classes this way as long as you are following one simple rule - your consumers are always expecting `ICommandHandler<,>`

So, if your constructor is written like this

```
public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer(ICommandHandler<CommandStub, ResultStub> handler)
    {
    }
}
```

Your implementations are registered something like this (i.e. as `ICommandHandler`'s)

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<,>), 
    typeof(ICommandHandler<,>).Assembly);
```

And your decorator is registered like this

```
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<,>),
    typeof(MockAuthorisationDecorator<,>));
```

then despite the fact that the implementation of `MockTransactionalCommandHandler` is written as inheriting from `ITransactionalCommandHandler<,>`

```
public class MockTransactionalCommandHandler : 
    ITransactionalCommandHandler<CommandStub, ResultStub> {
    public ResultStub Result { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }

    public void Handle(CommandStub command) { }
}
```

Your `Consumer` class will still be given an instance of `MockTransactionalCommandHandler` decorated with an instance of `MockAuthorisationDecorator`

A slight complication is introduced (with a simple solution) when you have a decorator that should only wrap some of the `ICommandHandler<,>`'s (in this case the decorators such as `MockUnitOfWorkDecorator<,>`) - to get this to work as you desire you need to define a `Predicate<>` as part of the decorator registration.

The registration for the `MockUnitOfWorkDecorator` would look something like this:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ICommandHandler<,>),
    typeof(MockUnitOfWorkDecorator<,>),
    context =>
    {
        var baseType = typeof(ITransactionalCommandHandler<,>);
        var type = baseType.MakeGenericType(
            context.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments());
        return type.IsAssignableFrom(context.ImplementationType);
    });
```